# DataSource not getting added to ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset, reportviewer

I am trying to configure a ReportViewer but have not been able to get it to work

I have the following DataSet:

[image: DataSet]

This is the query in the dataset:

```
SELECT        DataTime, DataValue
FROM            PointValue
WHERE        (DataTime >= @FromDate) AND (DataTime <= @ToDate)
```

I also have a report rdlc:

[image: Reportrdlc]

I have a button that runs this code when clicked:

```
var myDataTable = new i96X_dataDataSet.PointValueDataTable();
var myTableAdapter = new PointValueTableAdapter();
myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataTable, Convert.ToDateTime("2010-01-20T00:00:00.000"), Convert.ToDateTime("2010-01-21T00:00:00.000"));
var rds = new ReportDataSource("i96X_dataDataSet_PointValue", myDataTable as DataTable);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

But, when I run this, inside the ReportViewer is written:

A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'.

It looks like the right data is being collected because when I debug I see a count of 5990:

[image: Debug]

It seems that the datasource isn't getting added.

Obviously I am doing something wrong. Also, is there an easier way to achieve this? It seems a lot of work, I've been reading articles all day on this. All I want to do is to be able to adjust a SELECT statement attached to a SQL database somehow and retrieve that data into a report viewer.

Thanks for any guidance,

Julian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if your report was built on a data source called `DataSet1`.

Try changing this line ....

```
var rds = new ReportDataSource("i96X_dataDataSet_PointValue", myDataTable as DataTable);
```

... to this line ...

```
var rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", myDataTable as DataTable);
```

Or, you could modify the report and rename the datasource in the report definition.  If you have a lot of reports that you expect to use the same data source, that might make more sense.

Comment: Excellent, that's what was needed. It's probably because I'm new to programming but the whole way this ReportViewer works seems so convoluted for something that I thought was going to be straight forward. Anyway, thanks so much for the help.