# "a data source instance has not been created for dataset" no databindings and datasources found C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reporting

I have created a report using Visual Studio report wizard and using business objects as Data Source. I created my class first and added objects to it. Then I used the report wizard to create a report. Everything works fine until I add new objects/classes. Data Source starts disappaearing. I am aware that after creating a reportviewer, we should bind data sources using the smart tag(little triangle) or even "Choose Data Sources" to bind it with already excisiting data sources. But my data source pane is blank. Heres how it looks after I added a new class:
[image: blank data source]

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141831/datasource-not-getting-added-to-reportviewer) however since I am creating datasets using objects and not typed dataset, I didnt find it helpful. I have used the report wizard to generate a report for me therefore, I did not forget to write any datasource code (hopefully). Heres how my Form.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ReportsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Products m_products = new Products();
        private AlertsList m_alert = new AlertsList();
        private ActionsList m_actionsl = new ActionsList();
        private GradeList m_gradesl = new GradeList();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           this.PaperBindingSource.DataSource = m_products.GetProducts();
           this.AlertBindingSource.DataSource = m_alert.GetAlertsList();
           this.ActionBindingSource.DataSource = m_actionsl.GetActionsList();
           this.bindingSource1.DataSource = m_gradesl.GetGradeList();
           this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ActionBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this as an answer here for someone who is having the same problem:

What I learnt the hard way is to never use Report Wizard for creating a report and dataset. Report must be created manually without the wizard and the dataset must be drawn in the dataset designer. [Here is a my blog with detailed description](http://shrutikapoor-ubc.blogspot.com/2013/05/using-business-objects-in-report-viewer.html)